# Django not sending error messages to email

Tags: python, django

I used to be able to do this, not sure why it seems to no longer work. I want Django to email me whenever an error occurs like 500 server error, which would be useful since the email usually includes the detailed error description.

Here's one error I'm letting persist for now shown in chrome's terminal as I try and get this feature to work.

[image]

here's what I have in my settings file

```
ADMINS = ['<my_email>']

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = SERVER_EMAIL = '<server_email>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxxxxx" #
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

so even though this is an error it doesn't send any emails to my mail.

I can however send emails from the shell using

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    '<server_email>',
    ['<my_email>'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

from the same server

Comment: I think you should provide an error form log also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ADMINS` settings need to be a list of tuples with name and email in each tuple.

Example : `ADMINS = [('John', 'john@example.com'), ('Mary', 'mary@example.com')]`

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS